# Show and Hide Div onMouseOver

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys, need just a little bit of help here, it's very close to what I'm after but not quite.

I want the text links I hover over to animate hidden text in a target div. So when I hover over link A, that text fades in; when I hover over link B, the previous text fades away and new text fades in.

Here is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowHide(){
    $("#textMessages").animate({"height": "toggle"}, { duration: 1000 });
    }
</script>
```

Here are my links:

```
<a onMouseOver="ShowHide(); return false;" href="#">Message A</a>

<a onMouseOver="ShowHide(); return false;" href="#">Message B</a>

<a onMouseOver="ShowHide(); return false;" href="#">Message C</a>
```

And here is my target div with text snippets to fade in and fade out:

```
<div id="textMessages">

<div id="defaultMessage">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
</div>

<div id="MessageA">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
</div>

<div id="MessageB">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
</div>

<div id="MessageC">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
</div>

</div>
```

I assume I will need to set the #MessageA/B/C display:none

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a jsFiddle that does what I think you are trying to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/rcravens/md3Xe/

If that is not it, please provide additional information.

Bob

Comment: Bingo! Is there a way to animate the text? FadeIn/Out SlideUp/Down?

Comment: Sure, you can use 'fadeIn' and 'fadeOut' instead of 'show'/'hide'. Here is an example using the 'slideDown' / 'slideUp'. http://jsfiddle.net/rcravens/md3Xe/6/

Comment: Thanks! It's all perfect except I think I was unclear on the defaultMessage. That is what should be displayed when the user first visits, but as soon as they hover it will fade out and reappear only if nothing else is in hover state. Thanks for your help already!

Answer (score 1):

i've "improved" the answer by rcravens

http://jsfiddle.net/md3Xe/3/

Comment: This is also good, Alfred ... can you set it so that defaultMessage displays when there is no hover state and disappears when one of the links is hovered?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my bid:

```
$(function(){
    var slideOut = null;
    $('#textMessages').slideUp(1000);
    $('#textMessages,.textMessagesLink').hover(function(){
        $("#textMessages").slideDown(1000);
        if (slideOut != null) {
            clearTimeout(slideOut);
            slideOut = null
        }
    },function(){
        slideOut = setTimeout(HideHide,1000);
    });
    function HideHide(){
        $('#textMessages').slideUp(1000);
    }
});
```

Took advantage of a timer in doing so. Also, made small change to your links (added a class for reference) and made it so as long as you hover over the div, the div will also stay visible (easily modified by taking the '#textMessages,' out of the `.hover()` selector.

Working example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/zgbfa/1/
Another example of taking "content divs" into consideration: http://www.jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/zgbfa/3/ (Can play around with `defaultDiv` if you'd like as well.